# Not Enough Space to Install Ruby - Debian 7

Tags: ruby, debian, rvm

I am getting the following error when trying to install ruby with RVM as a root user.

I have 16gB of free space left, so that is not the issue

```
root@debian:~# rvm install 2.1.0
find: `/root/rvm/rubies': No such file or directory
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
Found remote file https://rvm.io/binaries/debian/7/i386/ruby-2.1.0.tar.bz2
Checking requirements for debian.
Requirements installation successful.
df: `/root/rvm/rubies': No such file or directory
df: no file systems processed
Not enough space (0MB) to install ruby (100MB).
ruby-2.1.0 - #configure
ruby-2.1.0 - #download
/root/rvm/scripts/functions/support: line 166: cd: /root/rvm/archives: No such file or directory
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 22.6M  100 22.6M    0     0   293k      0  0:01:18  0:01:18 --:--:--  417k
md5sum: /root/rvm/archives/bin-ruby-2.1.0.tar.bz2: No such file or directory
Downloaded archive checksum did not match, archive was removed!
If you wish to continue with not matching download add '--verify-downloads 2' after the command.

Downloading https://rvm.io/binaries/debian/7/i386/ruby-2.1.0.tar.bz2 failed.
Mounting remote ruby failed with status 2, trying to compile.
df: `/root/rvm/rubies': No such file or directory
df: no file systems processed
Not enough space (0MB) to install ruby (440MB).
```

I tried using --verify-downloads 2  but this did not help

```
root@debian:~# rvm install 2.1.0 --verify-downloads 2
find: `/root/rvm/rubies': No such file or directory
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
Found remote file https://rvm.io/binaries/debian/7/i386/ruby-2.1.0.tar.bz2
Checking requirements for debian.
Requirements installation successful.
df: `/root/rvm/rubies': No such file or directory
df: no file systems processed
Not enough space (0MB) to install ruby (100MB).
ruby-2.1.0 - #configure
ruby-2.1.0 - #download
/root/rvm/scripts/functions/support: line 166: cd: /root/rvm/archives: No such file or directory
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 22.6M  100 22.6M    0     0   378k      0  0:01:01  0:01:01 --:--:--  281k
md5sum: /root/rvm/archives/bin-ruby-2.1.0.tar.bz2: No such file or directory
Downloaded archive checksum did not match!
ruby-2.1.0 - #validate archive
tar (child): /root/rvm/archives/bin-ruby-2.1.0.tar.bz2: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar (child): /root/rvm/archives/bin-ruby-2.1.0.tar.bz2: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
The downloaded package for https://rvm.io/binaries/debian/7/i386/ruby-2.1.0.tar.bz2,
Does not contains single 'bin/ruby' or 'ruby-2.1.0',
Only '' were found instead.
Mounting remote ruby failed with status 4, trying to compile.
df: `/root/rvm/rubies': No such file or directory
df: no file systems processed
Not enough space (0MB) to install ruby (440MB).
root@debian:~#
```

Below is my step by step process of installing ruby on a brand new Debian 7 installation:

```
# Install RVM
sudo apt-get install libgdbm-dev libncurses5-dev automake libtool bison libffi-dev
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
sudo apt-get install curl
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
echo "source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm" >> ~/.bashrc




sudo apt-get install build-essential 
sudo apt-get install curl 
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev libreadline-dev libssl-dev libxml2-dev 
curl -sSL https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/tarball/stable -o rvm-stable.tar.gz
mkdir rvm && cd rvm
tar --strip-components=1 -xzf ../rvm-stable.tar.gz
./install --auto-dotfiles
echo "[[ -s "$HOME/rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/rvm/scripts/rvm"" >> .bashrc

#Restart BASH
# Install MRI Ruby
rvm list known
rvm install 2.1.0
rvm use 2.1.0 default
```

Can somebody help or let me know what I am installing incorrectly?

Thank you,
-D

Comment: What is the output of the `mount` command?

Comment: sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,relatime,size=10240k,nr_inodes=62990,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs

Comment: (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=51440k,mode=755)
/dev/disk/by-uuid/491518e6-6e70-41fc-b408-d21fef948040 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,user_xattr,barrier=1,data=ordered)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)

Comment: tmpfs on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=283100k)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
vmware-vmblock on /run/vmblock-fuse type fuse.vmware-vmblock (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other)
rpc_pipefs on /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw,relatime)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)

Answer (score 4):

I had issue on an Arch Linux Endevour OS distribution.
I tried several `rvm` installations modes, but I was still having some weird message

> df: /home/juanito/.rvm/rubies: No existe el fichero o el directorio
> Not enough space (0MB) to install ruby (440MB).

I had plenty free space on my hard drive.
I just created an empty directory:

```
mkdir ~/.rvm/rubies
```

And it started working.

Comment: Had also to add `~/.rvm/src` and `~/.rvm/archive`

Comment: this not work for me on ubuntu20

Answer (score 2):

Hi If you are still having issues with this, my solution was to go to this location

/usr/local/rvm/archives/rvm/scripts/functions/utility

Search for the line "df" and you will find this code

```
__rvm_calculate_space_free()
{
  # OpenBSD does not have 'df -m' param
  __free_space="$( \command \df "$1" | __rvm_awk 'BEGIN{x=4} /Free/{x=3} $3=="Avail"{x=3} END{print $x}' )"
  if [[ "${__free_space}" == *M ]]
  then __free_space="${__free_space%M}" # some systems ignore -k and print M
  else __free_space="$(( __free_space / 1024 ))"
  fi
}
```

Replace the line

```
 __free_space="$( \command \df "$1" | __rvm_awk 'BEGIN{x=4} /Free/{x=3} $3=="Avail"{x=3} END{print $x}' )"
```

with

```
__free_space="999999"
```

or whatever figure you want. This solved my problem

Comment: it's ridiculous to be in need for such a fix.

Answer (score 1):

You just found a bug in `/root/rvm` installation of RVM - but this type of installation is not supported and discouraged so I probably will not fix it.

The best course of action would be to remove your currently broken installation of RVM and start fresh using a user account (not `root`), if you prefer system installation use `sudo`.

Comment: I have the same issue and haven't done anything as root or sudo